# HTML escaped in document variables

Tags: docpad

I'm using the meta tags to fill in data for sub widgets that would be located on my layout pages.  Things like "widget title" and "widget content", along with the standard content area of the document.  My documents are *.html.md files (which shouldn't make a difference).

So I end up with something like this:

```
---
layout: layoutA
widgetTitle: This is a super awesome title
widgetBody: >
    Some in depth content for this widget<br /> With some html stuff
    potentially added <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
---

Some body content here
```

When I generate the app, using .html.eco as my layouts, all of the HTML content in the output file is escaped.  All of the tags turn into `&lt;br /<&gt;` style.

After looking through the config stuff, I didn't see anything that stood out as a "sanitize" or whatever.

Is there a way to not escape these variables?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this one, I realized that my .html.eco file was using the escaped version of it's output:

```
<%= @document.widgetBody %>
```

Instead of using

```
<%- @document.widgetBody %>
```

Hope this at least helps anyone else in this situation :)